# PHP doesn't echo this range properly

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$myarray = range(49500,49600);
foreach ($myarray as $key => $item) {
    echo "paper_crumbs[" .$key . "] = {type: HEAD, cost: 0, is_member: false}; <br />";
}
?>
```

Instead of echoing:

```
paper_crumbs[49500] = {type: HEAD, cost: 0, is_member: false}; 
paper_crumbs[49501] = {type: HEAD, cost: 0, is_member: false};
```

...etc...

with values all the way to 49,600 as expected, it goes from 0 to 100 like:

```
paper_crumbs[0] = {type: HEAD, cost: 0, is_member: false}; 
paper_crumbs[1] = {type: HEAD, cost: 0, is_member: false};
```

Many thanks in advance for assistance! This is my first time posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... you are echoing using the keys, and expect the values to just magically show up out of nowhere?

```
foreach(range(49500,49600) as $i) echo "paper_crumbs[".$i."] = ...<br />";
```

Comment: @user1470050 - Select the checkmark next to the answer to mark this question answered.

Comment: 8 minutes to go but that was a really fast response. You guys know your stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "paper_crumbs[" .$key . "] try "paper_crumbs[" .$item . "]

Answer (score 0):

Change `echo "paper_crumbs[" .$key . "]` to `echo "paper_crumbs[" .$item . "]`. The range is in the array values, not the keys.